# Before firing AJAX event, manipulate DOM -- CSRF Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, csrf

I'm working with Django, trying to make a chained AJAX call -- that is, a call that, when returned, kicks off more AJAX calls. I've been over the various methods of dealing with CSRF tokens and AJAX that the Django documentation provides, to no avail.

I have working code that allows for this chained AJAX call to successfully go through:

```
frm.submit(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken},
        success: function(data, status){
            $('#queue_div').append("<div class='container'>"+data['group_name']+"- "+data['client']+"<div id='queue"+counter+"'></div></div>");

            var div_id = 'queue'+counter;
            data['div_id'] = div_id;

            var token = $.cookie('csrftoken');
            data['csrf'] = token;

            $('#'+div_id).html(data['status']);

            callbackAJAX(data);
            } //end success function
    }); //end ajax function
    e.preventDefault();
```

But when you delay the form event from firing the AJAX event right away, either by using "beforeSend" (as below):

```
        var data = {'group_name':'name', 'client':'MrClient'}
        var counter = 0
        frm.submit(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken}
            beforeSend:function(e){
               $('#foo').append('<div class='container'>"+data['group_name']+"- "+data['client']+"<div id='queue"+counter+"'></div></div>');
             } .....
```

or by adding an event right before the $.ajax call (as below):

```
        frm.submit(function(e){
           $('#foo').append('<div class='container'>"+data['group_name']+"- "+data['client']+"<div id='queue"+counter+"'></div></div>');          
           $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method')....
```

You get a CSRF error.

I was successful in doing very, very simple functions such as the following:

```
        var counter = 0;
        frm.submit(function(e){         
           $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            sendBefore: function(e){
              counter++;
        }
```

But that's it. Anything more complicated gets rejected. I'm thoroughly confused as how to make heads or tails of what is actually happening OR what is acceptable to Django. & its CSRF protection.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you are trying to append is invalid. I believe that's why the form submission is not working. First you are trying to insert an element with ID `foo` into an element with the same ID ( `foo` ). Which is invalid HTML since IDs should never be repeated within the page.

Second and main problem is that you are appending `<div id=foo></div>` which should be `<div id="foo"></div>`

Comment: This was really example HTML -- the actual HTML was more complicated (as in the first codeblock). Editing now